# Problem with python tkinter when calling a function to display the input on the interface of the program?

Tags: python, database, tkinter

I wrote a program code on python tkinter for employee data
The database has been connected and the information has been entered into the table successfully:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pymysql

class Employee:
    # ----------- إنشاء نافذة البرنامج -----------
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry('1300x650+22+22') # الأرقام الإضافية بعد الطول والعرض (22) هي توصيت الشاشة مسافة من اليسار ومن الأعلى
        self.root.title('برنامج إدارة الموظفين')
        self.root.configure(background="#316df4")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        title = Label(self.root,
                      text='[بيانات الموظفين]',
                      bg='#316df4',
                      font=('monospace',18),
                      fg='white'
                      )
        title.pack(fill='x')

        # ----------- variable -----------
        # -------- variable = البيانات الشخصية --------
        self.id_var = StringVar()
        self.name_var = StringVar()
        self.mail_var = StringVar()
        self.id_number_var = StringVar()
        self.date_birth_var = StringVar()
        self.gender_var = StringVar()
        self.social_status_var = StringVar()
        self.family_var = StringVar()
        # -------- variable = معلومات الاتصال --------
        self.nationality_var = StringVar()
        self.id_photo_var = StringVar()
        self.country_var = StringVar()
        self.governorate_var = StringVar()
        self.city_var = StringVar()
        self.phone_var = StringVar()
        self.skype_var = StringVar()
        self.telegram_var = StringVar()

        # ----------- تقسيم لأختيارات علوية -----------
        nb = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        nb.place(x=900,y=34, width=400, height=460)

        f1 = Frame(nb, width='500', height='100', bg='#fff')
        nb.add(f1, text='بيانات شخصية')

        f2 = Frame(nb, width='500', height='100', bg='#fff')
        nb.add(f2, text='معلومات الاتصال')

        # ----------- أدوات التحكم  في البيانات الشخصية 1 -----------
        # Manage_Frame = Frame(self.root, bg='white')
        # Manage_Frame.place(x=10,y=190, width=200, height=460)
        lbl_ID = Label(f1, text='الرقم التسلسلي', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_ID.pack()
        ID_Entry = Entry(f1, textvariable=self.id_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        ID_Entry.pack()

        lbl_name = Label(f1, text='اسم الموظف', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_name.pack()
        Name_Entry = Entry(f1, textvariable=self.name_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        Name_Entry.pack()

        lbl_email = Label(f1, text='البريد الإلكتروني', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_email.pack()
        Email_Entry = Entry(f1, textvariable=self.mail_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        Email_Entry.pack()

        lbl_ID_Number = Label(f1, text='رقم الهوية', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_ID_Number.pack()
        ID_Number_Entry = Entry(f1, textvariable=self.id_number_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        ID_Number_Entry.pack()

        lbl_Date_Birth = Label(f1, text='تاريخ الميلاد', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_Date_Birth.pack()
        Date_Birth_Entry = Entry(f1, textvariable=self.date_birth_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        Date_Birth_Entry.pack()

        lbl_Gender = Label(f1, text='الجنس', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_Gender.pack()
        combo_Gender = ttk.Combobox(
            f1,
            value=('ذكر', 'أنثى'),
            state='readonly',
            textvariable=self.gender_var
        )
        combo_Gender.pack()

        lbl_Social_Status = Label(f1, text='الحالة الاجتماعية', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_Social_Status.pack()
        combo_Social_Status = ttk.Combobox(
            f1,
            value=('أعزب', 'متزوج'),
            state='readonly',
            textvariable=self.social_status_var
        )
        combo_Social_Status.pack()

        lbl_Family_Members = Label(f1, text='عدد أفراد الأسرة', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_Family_Members.pack()
        Family_Members_Entry = Entry(f1, textvariable=self.family_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        Family_Members_Entry.pack()

        # ----------- أدوات التحكم  في معلومات الاتصال 2 -----------
        # Manage_Frame = Frame(self.root, bg='white')
        # Manage_Frame.place(x=900, y=190, width=200, height=460)
        lbl_Nationality = Label(f2, text='الجنسية', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_Nationality.pack()
        Nationality_Entry = Entry(f2, textvariable=self.nationality_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        Nationality_Entry.pack()

        lbl_ID_Photo = Label(f2, text='صورة الهوية', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_ID_Photo.pack()
        ID_Photo_Entry = Entry(f2, textvariable=self.id_photo_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        ID_Photo_Entry.pack()

        lbl_Country = Label(f2, text='الدولة', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_Country.pack()
        Country_Entry = Entry(f2, textvariable=self.country_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        Country_Entry.pack()

        lbl_State = Label(f2, text='الولاية / المحافظة', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_State.pack()
        State_Entry = Entry(f2, textvariable=self.governorate_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        State_Entry.pack()

        lbl_City = Label(f2, text='المدينة', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_City.pack()
        City_Entry = Entry(f2, textvariable=self.city_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        City_Entry.pack()

        lbl_Phone_Number = Label(f2, text='رقم الموبايل', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_Phone_Number.pack()
        Phone_Number_Entry = Entry(f2, textvariable=self.phone_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        Phone_Number_Entry.pack()

        lbl_Skype = Label(f2, text='سكايب', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_Skype.pack()
        Skype_Entry = Entry(f2, textvariable=self.skype_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        Skype_Entry.pack()

        lbl_Telegram = Label(f2, text='تلغرام', bg='#fff', fg='#05234f', font=('monospace', 14))
        lbl_Telegram.pack()
        Telegram_Entry = Entry(f2, textvariable=self.telegram_var, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='center')
        Telegram_Entry.pack()

        # ----------- buttons الأزرار -----------
        btn_Frame = Frame(self.root, bg="#fff")
        btn_Frame.place(x=900, y=500, width=400, height=148)
        title2 = Label(btn_Frame, text='لوحة التحكم', font=('monospace', 16), bg='#316df4', fg='#fff')
        title2.pack(fill='x')

        add_btn = Button(btn_Frame, text='إضافة موظف', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', cursor='plus', command=self.add_student)
        add_btn.place(x=280, y=50, width=80, height=30)

        del_btn = Button(btn_Frame, text='حذف موظف', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', cursor='target')
        del_btn.place(x=165, y=50, width=80, height=30)

        update_btn = Button(btn_Frame, text='تعديل بيانات', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', cursor='circle')
        update_btn.place(x=50, y=50, width=80, height=30)

        clear_btn = Button(btn_Frame, text='إفراغ الحقول', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', cursor='sizing')
        clear_btn.place(x=280, y=100, width=80, height=30)

        exit_btn = Button(btn_Frame, text='إغلاق البرنامج', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', cursor='cross')
        exit_btn.place(x=165, y=100, width=80, height=30)

        about_btn = Button(btn_Frame, text='من نحن', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', cursor='heart', bitmap='info')
        about_btn.place(x=50, y=100, width=80, height=30)

        # ----------- search manage البحث -----------
        search_Frame = Frame(self.root, bg="#fff")
        search_Frame.place(x=2, y=35, width=896, height=50)

        lbl_search = Label(search_Frame, text='البحث', font=('monospace', 16), bg='#fff', fg='#05234f')
        lbl_search.place(x=830, y=12)

        combo_search = ttk.Combobox(search_Frame, justify='right')
        combo_search['value']=('الرقم التسلسلي', 'الاسم', 'الإيميل', 'رقم الهوية', 'الجنس', 'الحالة الاجتماعية', 'المدينة', 'رقم الهاتف', 'المؤهل العلمي', 'الجامعة', 'نوع المهارة', 'المسمى الوظيفي', 'المعرفة المهنية', 'برامج التصميم', 'برامج المونتاج', 'مهارات البرمجة')
        combo_search.place(x=680, y=14)

        search_Entry = Entry(search_Frame, bd='2', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', justify='right')
        search_Entry.place(x=545, y=14)

        search_btn = Button(search_Frame, text='بحث', bg='#05234f', fg='#fff', cursor='circle')
        search_btn.place(x=460, y=10, width=80, height=30)

        # ----------- dietals عرض النتائج والبيانات -----------
        Dietals_Frame = Frame(self.root, bg="#fff")
        Dietals_Frame.place(x=2, y=88, width=896, height=560)
            # -------- scroll --------
        scroll_x = Scrollbar(Dietals_Frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scroll_y = Scrollbar(Dietals_Frame, orient=VERTICAL)
            # -------- treeview --------
        self.student_table = ttk.Treeview(Dietals_Frame,
            columns=('Telegram', 'Skype', 'Phone', 'City', 'Governorate', 'Country', 'ID photo', 'Nationality',
                     'Family', 'Social Status', 'Gender', 'Date Birth', 'ID Number', 'E-mail', 'Name', 'ID'),
            xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set,
            yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
        self.student_table.place(x=20, y=2, width=890, height=540)
        scroll_x.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='x')
        scroll_y.pack(side=LEFT, fill='y')
        scroll_x.config(command=self.student_table.xview)
        scroll_y.config(command=self.student_table.yview)
        self.student_table['show'] = 'headings'

        self.student_table.heading('Telegram', text='تلغرام')
        self.student_table.heading('Skype', text='سكايب')
        self.student_table.heading('Phone', text='رقم الموبايل')
        self.student_table.heading('City', text='المدينة')
        self.student_table.heading('Governorate', text='المحافظة')
        self.student_table.heading('Country', text='الدولة')
        self.student_table.heading('ID photo', text='صورة الهوية')
        self.student_table.heading('Nationality', text='الجنسية')

        self.student_table.heading('Family', text='عدد أفراد الأسرة')
        self.student_table.heading('Social Status', text='الحالة الاجتماعية')
        self.student_table.heading('Gender', text='الجنس')
        self.student_table.heading('Date Birth', text='تاريخ الميلاد')
        self.student_table.heading('ID Number', text='رقم الهوية')
        self.student_table.heading('E-mail', text='البريد الإلكتروني')
        self.student_table.heading('Name', text='الاسم')
        self.student_table.heading('ID', text='الرقم التسلسلي')

        # ----------- con + add -----------
        self.fetch_all()
    def add_student(self):
        con = pymysql.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            password = '',
            database = 'stud')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("insert into student values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(
                    self.id_var.get(),
                    self.name_var.get(),
                    self.mail_var.get(),
                    self.id_number_var.get(),
                    self.date_birth_var.get(),
                    self.gender_var.get(),
                    self.social_status_var.get(),
                    self.family_var.get(),

                    self.nationality_var.get(),
                    self.id_photo_var.get(),
                    self.country_var.get(),
                    self.governorate_var.get(),
                    self.city_var.get(),
                    self.phone_var.get(),
                    self.skype_var.get(),
                    self.telegram_var.get()
                    ))
        con.commit()
        con.close()

    def fetch_all(self):
        con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user = 'root', password = '', database = 'employ')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('select * from employees')
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        if len (rows) !=0:
            self.student_table.delete(*self.student_table.get_children)
            for row in rows:
                self.student_table.insert("", END, value=row)
            con.commit()
        con.close()


root = Tk()
ob = Employee(root)
root.mainloop()
```

But after writing a new function to display those inputs on the program interface:

```
def fetch_all(self):
        con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user = 'root', password = '', database = 'employ')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('select * from employees')
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        if len (rows) !=0:
            self.student_table.delete(*self.student_table.get_children)
            for row in rows:
                self.student_table.insert("", END, value=row)
            con.commit()
        con.close()
```

When calling the function:

```
self.fetch_all()
```

It gives me the following error:

```
line 560, in fetch_all
    self.student_table.delete(*self.student_table.get_children)
TypeError: tkinter.ttk.Treeview.delete() argument after * must be an iterable, not method
```

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem.

It expects to get iterable for any indication of a particular purpose, while it receives a function, so the function must be called by **bracketing** it:

```
self.student_table.delete(*self.student_table.get_children())
                                                          ^^
```

Thank you to everyone who participated or tried to help.